# Spring MVC autowiring bean throws nestedexception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, autowired

I have big problems with autowiring in Spring MVC 4 and I already spent many hours on it. Found many solutions but nothing helps.

I have Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PrintedBookController {
    @Autowired
    PrintedBookService pbookService; // interface

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pbook", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView pbook() {
        return new ModelAndView("pbook", "command", new PrintedBookDTO());
    }
...
}
```

Also have:

```
PrintedBookService // this is interface

PrintedBookServiceImpl // this is implementation of PrintedBookService
```

in printedbookserviceimpl is:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PrintedBookServiceImpl implements PrintedBookService {

    @Autowired
    private PrintedBookDAO pbookDao;

    @Autowired
    private BookDAO bookDao;

    @Autowired
    private LoanDAO loanDao;


    public void setPrintedBookDao(PrintedBookDAO pbookDao) {
       this.pbookDao = pbookDao;
    }
    ....
}
```

the daos in PrintedBookServiceImpl are interfaces

The dao implementations look like this:

```
public class PrintedBookDAOImpl implements PrintedBookDAO, GenericDAO<PrintedBook> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pbook-unit", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;
    ....
}
```

I have three modules library-lib(daos) library-service(services) library-web(spring mvc).
Library mvc has controller xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="cz.fi.muni.pa165.library.web" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="cz.fi.muni.pa165.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="cz.fi.muni.pa165.dao" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

When i run the web(on tomcat8) it shows me exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: cz.fi.muni.pa165.service.PrintedBookServiceImpl cz.fi.muni.pa165.library.web.PrintedBookController.pbookService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'printedBookServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private cz.fi.muni.pa165.dao.PrintedBookDAO cz.fi.muni.pa165.service.PrintedBookServiceImpl.pbookDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cz.fi.muni.pa165.dao.PrintedBookDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

and

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'printedBookServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private cz.fi.muni.pa165.dao.PrintedBookDAO cz.fi.muni.pa165.service.PrintedBookServiceImpl.pbookDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cz.fi.muni.pa165.dao.PrintedBookDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

also getting this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pbookDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'pbook-unit' is defined
```

The project is on github https://github.com/Cospel/ProjLibrary
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You can find the ProjLibrary on github for more details in implementation. https://github.com/Cospel/ProjLibrary

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@Component` annotation on `PrintedBookDAOImpl`, Spring can't find any bean of type `PrintedBookDAO` in the context.

See this part of the trace :

`No qualifying bean of type [cz.fi.muni.pa165.dao.PrintedBookDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.`

Comment: Added but still get exception and now exception with pbook-unit.(entitymanager) No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Answer (score 0):

As Jean says, you need to add @Component to any class you wish to autowire.  For services, Spring provides some optimizations by using the @Service tag rather than the @Component tag.  Similarly, for the DAO layer, Spring provides an optimized @Repository annotation.  Use these annotations to enable these classes for component scanning.  Then, you shouldn't even need the

```
setPrintedBookDAO()
```

method at all, as Spring will take care of the autowiring for you.

Comment: Added but still get exception and now exception with pbook-unit.(entitymanager) No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined